# How to bypass json-smart:2.3-SNAPSHOT imported

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I am building a Java Maven Project and I have a dependency "net.minidev.json-smart:2.3-SNAPSHOT" imported in my package hbase 2.4.9 with another dependency and this displays a warning and Jenkins takes 1 or 2 minutes to resolve only this dependency.

the dependency tree is the following :

org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:2.4.9 -> org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:2.10 -> com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:4.41.1 -> net.minidev:json-smart:2.3-SNAPSHOT)

But when I exclude hadoop-auth 2.10 to use latest ...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.9</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have this dependency-tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
```

and when I build with `mvn -U clean install` I have this message:

```
[WARNING] The POM for net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

The debug logs do not say anything more

how can I completely remove it ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, we had to exclude com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt from hadoop-auth because of an odd transitive dependency. This ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14903 appears to relate to the problem. We are not using this updated version. Based on your error, maybe this "fix" didn't work.